# In-Game rules in professional CS:GO matches

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, competitive-gaming

I'm not all-too familiar with the professional competitive CS:GO scene (or shooters in general) but I occasionally play some shooters.

Now in professional RTS/MOBA tournaments the players are often allowed to ban certain elements of the game or some elements/strategies are even forbidden by the tournament rules. I wanted to know whether there are some specific rules in CS:GO tournaments that disallow the use of certain weapons and/or tactics (Camping/Bunnyhopping for example) and also if the teams have an opportunity to ban certain weapons.

Comment: this probably depends on the specific tournament in question.

Comment: FYI: banning camping in CS would not make sense. The whole goal of CT side of CS is to prevent bomb plants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know ( I watched a couple of them ), there are almost no limitations.

Camping and similar tactics are part of the game and are abolutely necessary.

Other tactics like crouching, getting one player to jump on you and then jumping 
together to push him on the roof are allowed as well and are used as much as they can.

The only time i witnessed problems are when they found a leak in the map where you could see through the wall.

Every weapon can be used.

CS:GO is designed to be as competetive as possible, banning weapons would ruin this. Also, there are no problems with skins or whatsoever ( unlike some LoL skins )

Comment: Well, basically evertyhing is allowed exept using bugs intentionally ( placing bombs in unreachable places,... ). If they weren't intentional they deal with it on the spot ( undo the round, ignore it,... )

Comment: What about when Fnatic exploited de_overpass with a boost that destroyed Dignitas(?)

Answer (score 2):

After a quick google search, I found the [RuleBook for EslOne](http://gfx.esl.eu/media/eu/csgo/eslone/cologne2014/ESLOne_CSGO_Rulebook.pdf). All I had to do was search up "Professional CS:GO Rules" and a lot popped up.

Edit: I also found a set of rules for [ESEA](http://play.esea.net/index.php?s=content&d=league_rules_CSGO)

Comment: Please summarize the information contained at the links.  That way, if the pages ever go down, your answer is still valid.

Comment: @Frank Just because an answer contains little more than a link doesn't make it a non answer. Especially when the question is "What Are The Rules" and the answer is a link to The Rules, which comprise a 30 page document. Demanding a summary *reduces* the utility of the answer in this case, in my experience. Furthermore, given that tournament rules are fluid and subject to be changed by their officiating bodies, a link is, in fact, *more likely* to remain valid than any snapshot of their current state as summarized today.

Answer (score 0):

In CS:GO, the only thing similar to what you are citing is the map selection process used for the match itself.

This is a process very similar to MOBA champion selection. Each team is given a certain number of bans/picks. Then they execute these bans/picks in a structured fashion and the result is the map(s) they will use for the match.